# Qt: Cannot read device, no error provided

Tags: c++, qt, uart

I have some code for Qt below that connects two devices via UART if possible. If not possible, it will display an error string.

```
void Hardware::initialisePort(QString portName)     //Initialized at balance and controlboard
{
    /*! \brief Method to initialise the com port
     *
     */

    // setup the port in the appropriate way for the platform that the code is compiled for
    this->serialPort = new QextSerialPort(portName, QextSerialPort::EventDriven);   //serialPort now points to this new QextSerialPort, and the string will come from this port.

    // setup port settings
    serialPort->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
    serialPort->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    serialPort->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    serialPort->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    serialPort->setStopBits(STOP_1);

    // attempt to open the port for both reading and writing
    if (serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) == true)
    {
        // connect the port ready to read signal to the handling slot
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(serialDataReady()));    //readyRead is just signal, not function, serialDataReady is function that breaks up Arduino string

        qDebug() << "Listening for data on" << serialPort->portName();

    }
    else // could not open port communications
    {

        qDebug() << "Device failed to open:" << serialPort->errorString() << ":" << portName;

        // print the issue to the log with the port error string
        //logging() << "Could not open serial port connection: " << serialPort->errorString();
    }
}
```

I have two ports initialized, as below:

```
Balance::Balance() :
    Hardware()
{
    // initialise members
    // null values for the unallocated masses
    lastStableMass = -1;
    lastUnstableMass = -1;
    stable = false;
    timeoutStatus = 0;
    hasTimedOut = false;
    calibrationInProgress = false;
    tareOffset = 0;

    this->initialisePort("/dev/tty01"); //Port name is /dev/tty01

    timer.setInterval(2000);
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(resend()));
    timer.start();
}
```

```
ControlBoard::ControlBoard(QObject *obj) :
    Hardware(obj)
{
    /*! \brief Constructor
     *
     */

    this->initialisePort("/dev/ttyO4"); //Port name is /dev/tty04, and that is somewhere on the control board, don't worry about it
    //Initialise port is in hardware.cpp

    this->airTempMessage = "";
    this->valveChangeMessage = "";
    acknowledgementTimer = 0;
    calibrationTimer = 0;
    sendCalibration = -1;

    this->sampleTempTimer = new QTimer;
    connect(sampleTempTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(requestSampleTempUpdate()));

    hasTimedOut = false;

    valveOpen = false;

    airTemperature = 0;

    temporaryCalFactor = -1;

    compressorTimer = 0;

    requestValveUpdate();
}
```

This is something I have received with the code:

```
Device failed to open: "No Error has occurred" : "/dev/tty01" 
Listening for data on "/dev/ttyO4"
```

I am unsure why. I have attempted to do the following:

```
    else // could not open port communications
    {
        connect(serialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(serialDataReady()));
        //Even though the port is listed as cannot be opened, I attempted to see whether the error signal was a false flag by initializing it anyways.
        qDebug() << "Device failed to open:" << serialPort->errorString() << ":" << portName;

        // print the issue to the log with the port error string
        //logging() << "Could not open serial port connection: " << serialPort->errorString();
    }
```

This did not result in the port actually opening. Please let me know if more information is required to solve this issue; I will update this question accordingly.

Comment: Did you check the access rights of your /dev/tty01? Also is it /dev/ttyO4 or /dev/tty04 (like in your comment in your code)?

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my issue, it's ttyO1 and not tty01. Mind typing up an answer? I'm still not used to how similar Os and 0s look in Linux and I think there are others who are in the same boat.

Comment: Just as a little tip: to display errors use `qWarning()` or `qError()` instead of `qDebug()`.

Comment: What's the benefit of qWarning or qError over qDebug?

Comment: quick comment, maybe unrelated but `QextSerialPort` is a ancient library. It has not been updated since 2015. Also Qt has a first party `SerialPort` module now which have similar API and is certainly more stable / up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo. The port was written as "tty01", when it should have been "ttyO1", O for Orange instead of a zero. Thanks to chehrlic for catching it, 0s and Os are a bit too similar in Linux.